# Open a third party page and close based on a condition in same tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, payment-gateway, payment

How can we close an already opened external page based on some condition. The application which we are working on is a Ionic-Angular application supporting PWA(Progressive Web App).

Current implementation done is, opening the external URL in a new window and based on some condition closing the window which is already opened. Below is the sample code for reference

```
 var windowInst = window.open(`EXTERNAL URL LINK`);
     let obs = interval(15000).subscribe(x => {
        this.service.getConfirmation(id).subscribe(res => {
          let response = res[0];
          if (response?.msg.includes('True')) {
            windowInst.close();
            obs.unsubscribe();
          } 
        })
      });
```

In the above code the problem is window.open is triggred after some API call because of which pop block issue is observed and window.open is not triggered/opened in mobile/web browsers.

So is there a way to open the **external page in the same window and close the external page based on some condition** ?

Here the workflow which we are targeting is a External Payment Page integration in the ionic-angular application. Please let me know if there is some particular workflow to be followed to achieve the same.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you find solution to this?